# Stanza: Count words without punctuation

Tags: python, stanford-nlp

I currently want to count words in a text with stanza, but without punctuation and without removing punctuation.
Currently I try:

```
text = """ Q1 revenue reached €12 .7 billion ."""
doc = nlp ( text )
words = doc.num_tokens
print(words)
```

8

Sorry if this is too basic, but I am very new to Stanza.
Could you please explain how i Measure words without punctuation?

Comment: what is the answer you are expecting?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to remove the punctuation, You can provide a keyword argument to pipeline `tokenize_pretokenized` and set it to `True`.

This will disable the tokenization, you will get the word count without punctuations

```
nlp = stanza.Pipeline(tokenize_pretokenized=True)

text = """ Q1 revenue reached €12 .7 billion ."""
doc = nlp(text)
words = doc.num_tokens
print(words) # 7
```

Comment: Thank you, it works so much. How would I come up with this on my own? Is this from a wiki or something?

Comment: it's in the documentation, you can check it there